# Why does a graph with n vertices have 2^n -2 cuts?

Tags: graph

Why  does a graph with n vertices have 2^n -2 cuts?  I can't figure this one out. With 4 vertices, I just cant get 14 cuts. I can get max. 12 cuts? What am I missing?

By cut , I mean V is divided into 2 pairs of non-empty vertex list- A and B.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A simple way to rationalize it, as well as enumerate the cuts, is to assign a binary digit for each node. A 0 indicates it's in set A and a 1 that it's in set B. Then simply increment, ignoring the case of 0 and 2^n - 1, leaving 2^n - 2 cuts. So, for a 4 vertex graph with vertices P,Q,R,S:

```
PQRS
0000 A : { P,Q,R,S } B : {} // ignore, B is empty
0001 A : { P,Q,R } B : { S }
0010 A : { P,Q,S } B : { R }
0011 A : { P,Q } B : { R,S }
0100 A : { P,R,S } B : { Q }
0101 A : { P,R } B : { Q,S }
0110 A : { P,S } B : { Q,R }
0111 A : { P } B : { Q,R,S }
1000 A : { Q,R,S } B : { P }
1001 A : { Q,R }, B : { P,S } 
1010 A : { Q,S } B : { P,R }
1011 A : { Q } B : { P,R,S }
1100 A : { R,S } B : { P,Q }
1101 A : { R } B : { P,Q,S }
1110 A : { S } B : { P,Q,R }
1111 A : {} B : { P,Q,R,S } // ignore, A empty
```

That leaves you 14, 2^4 - 2.

Comment: Right, I understand now. Actually, this is the theoretical max, the actual no. of cuts might be less based on the structure of the graph, isn't it so? I was taking a square, with its diagonals, and could only arrive at 12.Hence the query.

Comment: No, there will always be 2^n - 2 cuts in the graph. Don't be tricked by the visual arrangement of a graph, i.e., cuts that are restricted to a plane.

Comment: My initial count for graph with 4 vertices was 6 based on visualization. But then after considering your answer I went back and realized I was only looking at straight line cuts. But the cuts can may not always be a straight line.

Comment: But you are counting all cuts twice. S/T is the same as T/S.

Comment: @vcardillo: yes you are correct if we think of it that way. But the definition is vertices in two disjoint sets.

Answer (score 6):

Your last sentence says it - a cut is simply a partition of the vertex set into two sets, neither of which is empty.

Hence, to define a particular cut, you just take some subset of V and that defines A, and also B, its complement.

The number of subsets of V, where |V| = n is the cardinality of the power set of V, 2^n. However you have to subtract two cases because A can't be empty, nor can it be equal to V, because then B would be empty. Hence 2^n - 2.

Comment: thank you. Yes, I understood the probability part of it,I specifically wanted to know how to get 14 cuts for 4 vertex graph.

Answer (score 6):

This is fairly obvious I think:

- Each vertex can either be in set A or set B
- We have n vertices
- Two possibilities on n vertices makes for 2^n permutations
- Removing the onces where all vertices are either in A or B
- That gives us 2^n - 2

Or think of it as a truth table. `a` means a vertex is in set A, `b` means it is in set B.

```
Vertices
1 2 3 4
a a a a
a a a b
a a b a
a a b b
a b a a
a b a b
a b b a
a b b b
b a a a
b a a b
b a b a
b a b b
b b a a
b b a b
b b b a
b b b b
```

If we remove  the `a a a a` and `b b b b` sets we are left with the needed 14...

Answer (score 1):

A cut implies that a vertex will either be in one Set A or in Set B.

Since both sets have to be non-empty, following is the only possibility.

1, (n-1) ==> This implies 1 vertex in Set A, and (n-1) in Set B. No of ways of choosing 1 out of n = nC1

2, (n-2) ==> 2 vertices in Set A and (n-2) in Set B. No of ways of choosing 2 out of n = nC2

3, (n-3) ==> 3 vertices in Set A and (n-3) in Set B. No of ways of choosing 3 out of n = nC3

(n-1), 1 ==> (n-1) vertices in Set A and 1 in Set B. No of ways of choosing n-1 out of n = nCn-1

Hence Total No of cuts are:

```
nC1 + nC2 + nC3 + ..... nCn-1 = 2^(n)-2
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, I went into similar problem while counting how many cuts are there for 4 vertices (square).

Do remember that you can cut by diagonal of the square. This will give you the missing 2.